# Java Generic extends subclass Incompatible types

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class, inner-classes

First, I've looked at a lot of previous posts, including:

[Java Generics and generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908742/java-generics-and-generic-types)

[Java generics incompatible type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909153/java-generics-incompatible-type)

[Java Generics Incompatible Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29594339/java-generics-incompatible-types)

[Java generics: incompatible types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497652/java-generics-incompatible-types)

None of them address the issue I'm having. The following code is somewhat contrived, but illustrates the problem. I'm using Java 1.8.

```
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by aaron on 11/8/2017.
 */
public abstract class Selecter<STATE extends Selecter.State, ACTION> {
    public abstract class State {
        public abstract List<ACTION> getActions();
        public abstract ACTION selectAction(List<ACTION> list, int selector);
    }

    public ACTION searchAction(STATE state, int selector) {
        return state.selectAction(state.getActions(), selector);
    }
}
```

Now, since `STATE` must be a `Selector.State`, and `getActions()` returns a `List<ACTION>` and `selectAction()` returns an `ACTION` from a `List<ACTION>`, why is there an incompatible types error in `searchAction()`?

How can I fix it?

*EDIT*

I think I've fixed it:

```
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by aaron on 11/8/2017.
 */
public abstract class Selecter<ACTION> {
    public abstract class State<A> {
        public abstract List<A> getActions();
        public abstract A selectAction(List<A> list, int selector);
    }

    public ACTION searchAction(State<ACTION> state, int selector) {
        return state.selectAction(state.getActions(), selector);
    }
}
```

However, I don't know why this works and the other doesn't.

Comment: State.selectAction(state.getActions(), selector)

Comment: What do you mean by "incompatible types"? Please post the relevant error message here. Also show the definition for `ACTION`

Comment: `<STATE extends Selecter<STATE, ACTION>.State, ACTION>` to make it compile, but this is ridiculous. Please find another way to model your use case, whatever it is.

Comment: The error was Incompatible types: Required: ACTION Found: Java.lang.Object

Comment: In your first version, couldn't you simply use `State state`, and drop the `STATE` type variable altogether?

Comment: public ACTION searchAction(State state, int selector) has the same error. 

And I realize it is ridiculous. I'm trying to understand Generics better, and trying to figure out why it doesn't work, not why it's terrible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your original attempt doesn't work because you're using raw types.

```
class Selecter<STATE extends Selecter.State, ACTION>
                              ^ Selecter is generic, missing type variables.
```

As such, if you try to use a `STATE`, the generics are erased. So in:

```
public ACTION searchAction(STATE state, int selector) {
    return state.selectAction(state.getActions(), selector);
}
```

the return value is of type `Object`, not `ACTION`, because that's the upper bound of `ACTION`.

You could add the type variables, as suggested by Sotirios:

```
class Selecter<STATE extends Selecter<STATE, ACTION>.State, ACTION>
```

but that is pretty messy.

`State` is an inner class of `Selecter`, so it inherits its type variables. As such:

```
public abstract class Selecter<ACTION> {
    public abstract class State {
        public abstract List<ACTION> getActions();
        public abstract ACTION selectAction(List<ACTION> list, int selector);
    }

    public ACTION searchAction(State state, int selector) {
        return state.selectAction(state.getActions(), selector);
    }
}
```

seems like the easiest solution. [This compiles fine](https://ideone.com/gaMX2t).